# Why Hadoop Mapreduce distributed processing takes longer than normal sequential processing?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I wrote a simple code in Java to read csv file, make slight changes in the lines (using hashes), and then write to the output file.

I wanted to compare sequential version (plain java) and MapReduce version of the code. (Codes doesn't have much difference).

I tried codes both in pseudo-distributed hadoop (single node) and fully-distributed hadoop (3 nodes), but to my surprise, the time of execution of MapReduce version is always higher than that of sequential (Approx twice or thrice).

I don't have much experience in Hadoop, but at least distributed processing should take less time than serial processing (because that's why we have distributed processing). I even tried on varying dataset size.

Comment: Try the same setting with a possibly very large csv file so as to make use of the overhead that hadoop did with distributing

Answer (score 2):

Every parallel algorithm has an additional overhead compared to its sequential counterpart - this overhead can be thread creation and maintenance on a single machine, but mainly it's communication overhead - distributing the initial data, IPC (interprocess communication), collecting the partial results and/or combining it.

The efficiency of the algorithm relies on various factors - obviously the input size, but also number of nodes you use for the computation - see [isoefficiency](http://parallelcomp.uw.hu/ch05lev1sec4.html). Using more machines does not always mean faster processing times. With the use isoefficiency equations, you can compute how many nodes should you use for a fixed problem size to maximize the efficiency.

Your question does not provide detailed information like what algorithm did you use and what instances did you provide, but I would expect that for very large instances, your distributed system should be faster that its sequential counterpart.